# Hide left column DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I'm creating a Visual Basic program in VS2010. I'm using a DataGridView to display a .csv, but I don't want to show the left column, it's ugly.

Is there any form to hide it?

[image]

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Try setting the `RowHeadersVisible` property of your DataGridView to False.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can do it, setting the RowHeadersVisible property of your DataGridView to False

[image: look this]